# Could problem of three consecutive powerful numbers be manipulated in this manner?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Please do not link this to my earlier question.] I have been trying to find as simple solution to the problem as possible. The powerful numbers may be written in form $A^2B^3$, where *A* and *B* are positive integers. According to *Beckon* [Beckon, Edward (2019), ”On Consecutive Triples of Powerful Numbers”, *Rose-Hulman Undergraduate Mathematic Journal*, Vol. 20: Iss. 2, Article 3]:

if a triplet of consecutive powerful numbers exists, then the powerful numbers belong to one of the following alternatives:
$$(36k+7, 36k+8, 36k+9) = (A^2B^3, (A^2B^3+1), (A^2B^3+2))$$
$$(36k+27, 36k+28, 36k+29) =  (A^2B^3, (A^2B^3+1), (A^2B^3+2))$$
$$(36k-1, 36k, 36k+1) =  (A^2B^3, (A^2B^3+1), (A^2B^3+2))$$

where *k* is positive integer. The largest and the smallest powerful number of the powerful triplet must be odd and the powerful number between them must be even and divisible by 4.

It is possible to utilize the following three alternatives:

$$(36k+7)(36k+9)+1=16(9k+2)^2$$
$$(36k+27)(36k+29)+1=16(9k+7)^2$$
$$(36k-1)(36k+1)+1=16(81k)^2$$

Additionally, it is possible to utilize an average of the powerful numbers and the fact that the middle powerful number is divisible by 4:

$$A^2B^3(A^2B^3+2)+1=\left[\frac{A^2B^3+2+A^2B^3}{2}\right]^2$$

$$\frac{A^2B^3+1}{4}=p$$

where *p* is a positive integer.

Examine now the first alternative. According to *Beckon*, the largest powerful number is divisible by 9 in this alternative:

$$\frac{A^2B^3+2}{9}=d$$

where *d* is a positive integer. We may now write

$$36dA^2B^3+4=(4p+1+A^2B^3)^2=>9p=\pm2 \sqrt{9A^2B^3d+1}-A^2B^3-1$$

Only positive square root is possible. Note that $A^2B^3+1=4p$. We may now write $13p=2\sqrt{9A^2B^3d+1}$ and we can replace $1=4p-A^2B^3$ within the square root.

$$13p=2\sqrt{9A^2B^3d+4p-A^2B^3}=>338p = \pm \sqrt{676 A^2 B^3 (36 d - 4) + 256} + 16$$

Here, negative sign is not possible. Note $36d-4=4A^2B^3+4$. We have the following result

$$338p = \sqrt{676 A^2 B^3 (4 A^2B^3 + 4) + 256} + 16$$

This results in $A^2B^3=-1$ when *p* is replaced by $p=\frac{A^2B^3+1}{4}$.

Performing a corresponding manipulation to the second alternative, where $\frac{A^2B^3}{9}=d$, leads to $A^2B^3 = \frac{1}{23} (137 \pm 8 \sqrt{354})$, which is not possible because $A^2B^3$ is a positive integer.

The third alternative, where $\frac{A^2B^3+1}{9}=d$, has the same result as the first alternative. Hence, assuming the above is correct, three consecutive powerful numbers do not exist.

Comment: @EricSnyder Might you like to comment on this?

Comment: this is the third supposed proof of this outstanding conjecture you have posted over the past few weeks.  The other two had simple arithmetic errors, so....

Comment: More broadly, this is not a good site for reviewing supposed elementary proofs of major problems.  People generate hundreds if not thousands of such "proofs" for each of the elementary conjectures each year.  If we here agreed to review all of them there'd be little else in the site.

Comment: In $$36dA^2B^3+4=(4p+1+A^2B^3)^2=>9p=\pm2 \sqrt{9A^2B^3d+1}-A^2B^3-1$$ it seems $4p$ has changed to $9p$.

Comment: I am sorry. I hope, the past is not guarantee of the future.

Comment: That *4p* has changed to *9p* seems to be true. Still, the final result keeps the same i.e. $A^2B^3=-1$.

Comment: All of your equations treat $A^2 B^3$ as a unit, and never uses the fact it's a powerful number. If I replace $A^2 B^3$ with $C$ everywhere, you have "proved" that $36k+7 = -1$ for every positive integer $k$.